# How to give a sequence number to an Item?

Tags: swift, core-data

Trying to add a sequence number to each Item in my Core Data for exponential smoothing.

```
exp.i=alpha**Yi-1+(1-alpha)*Yexp.i-1
```

The idea is to have a "ids" attribute in the main entity ("Item") and another Entity ("Numb") with "number" attribute. "Number" is growing each time a new Item is added. I'm using this code in "persistence":

```
func editNumber(dai: Numb, day: Item, ids: Double, number: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        day.ids = number + 1
        dai.number = day.ids
        print(day.ids)
        save(context: context)
    }
```

But it gives an error:

```
Thread 1: "-\[BrainLab.Item setIds:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000015ae3c0".
```

So is it a right way to give sequence numbers and how to go throw the error?

Comment: The error means that there is no attribute `ids` in `Item`.

Comment: Try cleaning the build folder. Your coredatamodel and object model are likely out of sync and need to be re-generated.

Comment: It doesn't help(

Comment: Numb number]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000093a140